# Shell Scripting if then else loop with scp

Tags: shell

```
User=0
av="653"
ma="727"
pr="713"
mi="234"
n=192.168.1.20:/root/Ma
echo "Please select av ma ji im pr"
echo -n "First 2 initial of your Name eg: [av ma ji im pr]? "
read User
if [ "$User" = av ]
then
    echo `scp $User@$n .`
elif [ "$User" = ma ]
then    
    echo `scp $User@$n .`
elif [ "$User" = pr ]
then
    echo `scp $User@$n .`
elif [ "$User" = mi ]
then
    echo `scp $User@$n .`
else
    echo "UNKNOWN USER"
fi
```

The script is not working properly; I want the value of `av` which is 653

Comment: There's no need to have blank lines between *every* line of your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you after:

```
User=0
av="653"
ma="727"
pr="713"
mi="234"
n=192.168.1.20:/root/Ma
echo "Please select av ma ji im pr"
echo -n "First 2 initial of your Name eg: [av ma ji im pr]? "
read User
if [ "$User" = av ]
then echo `scp $av@$n .`
elif [ "$User" = ma ]
then echo `scp $ma@$n .`
elif [ "$User" = pr ]
then echo `scp $pr@$n .`
elif [ "$User" = mi ]
then echo `scp $mi@$n .`
else echo "UNKNOWN USER"
fi
```

If not, please clarify your question so it is clearer what you are seeking.  I'm also not clear why you have the `` echo `scp $xy@$n .` `` notation — what is the benefit of that compared with just `scp $xy@$n .`?

```
scp="echo scp"  # For testing; you'd use just scp=scp in production work
User=0
av="653"
ma="727"
pr="713"
mi="234"
n=192.168.1.20:/root/Ma
echo "Please select av ma ji im pr"
echo -n "First 2 initial of your Name eg: [av ma ji im pr]? "
read User
if [ "$User" = av ]
then $scp $av@$n .
elif [ "$User" = ma ]
then $scp $ma@$n .
elif [ "$User" = pr ]
then $scp $pr@$n .
elif [ "$User" = mi ]
then $scp $mi@$n .
else echo "UNKNOWN USER"
fi
```

When I tested the script above (file `xx.sh`), the output was:

```
$ bash xx.sh
Please select av ma ji im pr
First 2 initial of your Name eg: [av ma ji im pr]? mi
scp 234@192.168.1.20:/root/Ma .
$
```

Note that in `bash`, you could use [indirect expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to simplify the code:

```
scp="echo scp"  # For testing; you'd use just scp=scp in production work
User=0
av="653"
ma="727"
pr="713"
mi="234"
n=192.168.1.20:/root/Ma
echo "Please select av ma ji im pr"
echo -n "First 2 initial of your Name eg: [av ma ji im pr]? "
read User
case "$User" in
(av|ma|pr|mi) $scp ${!User}@$n . ;;
(*) echo "UNKNOWN USER"
esac
```

This gives the same result as the prior script for the same input.

Comment: I am doing this "echo `scp $xy@$n ." cause i need the command in this way, if the user running this command and types "mi" then  scp 234@192.168.1.20:/root/Ma .   This command will run

Comment: And what would you get with ``then echo `scp $mi@$n .` `` that is different from what you'd get using `then scp $mi@$n .`?  About the only thing I can see that's different is that the backticks and echo ensure that all the error messages appear before any standard output, and I'm not convinced that's a benefit.

Comment: i get mi@192.168.1.20:/root/Ma .

Comment: Both thing are same  With backticks and with out echo `backticks`

Comment: You do?  I don't see how that's possible with the code I showed.  If you're using your `scp $User@$n .` notation, then of course you get the `mi` in the expanded text; I was assuming you were at least trying the code in my answer which doesn't use `$User` in the `scp` commands.

Comment: Now i have removed the echo `backticks` still i am not getting "mi" as 234

Comment: Edit your question to add the modified script.  I can't see what you're doing wrong; I've shown you what I think works.

Comment: I interested to understand what you did between that case esac if you can explain

Comment: Is it the `case` code that is puzzling, or the `${!User}`?  I pointed to the `bash` manual where `${!User}` is documented.  The `case` code looks at the string in `$User` and if it matches the regex `(av|ma|pr|mi)` does the `scp` action, otherwise (`(*)`) it reports that the user is unknown.

Comment: It was a big bouncer for me but still I appreciate you effort for helping me